# Animating particles based on their speed

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

Using the legacy particle system, is it possible to - instead of animating the particles over their lifetime - animate them over a speed range?

I'm trying to get the shape of a particle changed as it goes faster, the "stretch" option won't work because simply stretching them won't look good, so I think the only option I have is to use UV animation.

Comment: ParticleSystem component has "Size by speed" option

Comment: I really need to change their shape.